# Textbox id which is created in loop

Tags: c#, jquery

I want id of each textbox on change event of textbox.I have done code for this but I am not getting expected result.I am getting value of textbox here which is "Amount" in each textbox.

Here is my html code:--

```
  @foreach (var item in ViewBag.countries)
     {                                                         
      <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, new { id = item.ID })</td>
     }
```

Here is my jquery code:--

```
  $('input[type="text"]').change(function () {
            var id = this.id;
            alert(id);
        });
```

Comment: Use `@Html.Editor` instead of `@Html.EditorFor`

Comment: U need item id or text box id? Because both are different approaches

Answer (score 0):

If I'm guessing right, your `Editorfor` value is incorrect. In this case it should be `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, Model.Amout, new {id = item.ID})`. Try this, I think it should work.

It's because the second parameter of the `EditorFor` binds with the model, and it is not an Html attribute.

Moreover, I would suggest you always work with a `for` loop in a view because the binding may cause troubles with a foreach loop.

So in your case it would look like this:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < ViewBag.countries.Count; i++)
{
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, Model.Amount, new { id = item.ID })
    </td>
}
```

A thorough explanation : http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: Oh, and I'd recommend switching to a for loop.

Comment: why would you recommend for loop?

Comment: just faster...  it isn't that big of a deal.

Comment: It's also because the binding may cause troubles. See how the view is rendered with a foreach VS for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using something like:

```
new { data_id = item.id }
```

simply because the ID attribute is being overwritten by the EditorFor helper in order to be correctly mapped to your model. Both ID and name attributes should not be messed with if you are using EditorFor.

Instead use what I said above and then fetch like this:

```
$('input[type="text"]').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

Also make sure your ViewBag.Countries has the correct values for country IDs...

1 more thing: "this" is not the same as "$(this)". In the case of your JQuery code you need to have $(this) if you mean to reference the element that triggered the change event...

Comment: yes..Viewbag.countries provides correct ID but the above code also not giving me expected output as I want ID of text boxes those I have defined explicitly.